# I get text widgets drawn with underline Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm building my first web project.
So the project is structured like so: 
Web: Is a web site, one of the pages (`RetailerAccess`) is an actual app that should be compatible with all devices.
In order to do so I use platform check in `main()` and return the proper screen.

```
home: kIsWeb
            ? Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
//        color: Colors.white,
                    child: AnimatedBackground(),
                  ),
                  LayoutTemplate()
                ],
              )
            : RetailerAccess());
```

It works as expected.. When running on browser shows the web page and you can navigate to `RetailerAccess` while if running on iPad starts directly on `RetailerAccess`.
So far so good.
The weird part is that text widgets are drawn with a double green underline where running on device while when running on browser are drawn normally.
Are you aware of any bug that makes it behave like this or is there something I should set in a specific way?

I tried running it in Release mode on an old iPad 3 running iOS 9.3.5 but no changes..

Thank you very much for your help.

Update:

I realised I don't have a `Scaffold` in `RetailerAccess` wrapped it with a `Material` widget and it solved it.
Shouldn't a theme been passed to `RetailerAccess` anyways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because you don't have a `scaffold` widget.
Try the code below:
It works perfectly:

```
home: kIsWeb
            ? Scaffold(
            Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
//        color: Colors.white,
                    child: AnimatedBackground(),
                  ),
                  LayoutTemplate()
                ],
              )
            ),
            : Scaffold( 
            RetailerAccess()
            );
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community, thanks for answering, I was editing my question as I realized I didn't have a Scaffold.. I wrapped it with a Material widget  and it worked..

Comment: Well I did use a Material widget and it solved it dough I should probably use a Scaffold instead as you suggested. Thank you again.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes you need a ```material``` Widget then a ```scaffold``` widget set as the ```home``` property.

Comment: `Scaffold(body: RetailerAccess())` actually works, but I'm wondering if I shouldn't use a Scaffold directly in`RetailerAccess` instead as I would normally do for any screen in an app..

Comment: You can use the ```scaffold``` widget there also, doesn't give any cost implication. I hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed I'll use a Scaffold directly in the screen build..Thanks for the help again

Comment: if your  `RetailerAccess()` alread has a scafold no need of adding one again